# Mute NotFoundHttpException from logs

Tags: logging

I'm getting a lot of noise in the logs from requests that are auto generated from browsers and spiders (like favico.ico, robots.txt, /home /news etc) that doesn't actually have any endpoints.

These get caught by index.php and throws

```
[yii\web\HttpException:404] yii\web\NotFoundHttpException: Template not found: new in /app/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/TemplatesController.php:93"
```

Which is causing a tremendous amount of noise. I would never consider a 404 a real error, so I would like to not log this at all in Craft (I can use access log aggregation for this).

However, I'm not sure how to go about it. I have already created a custom log component, to remove the logging of all server variables on error, and send outputs to stderr (because of docker), with `yii2-streamlog`.

My log config is as follows:

```
    'components' => [
        'log' => function() {
            return Craft::createObject([
                'class' => yii\log\Dispatcher::class,
                'targets' => [
                    [
                        'class' => codemix\streamlog\Target::class,
                        'url' => 'php://stderr',
                        'levels' => Logger::LEVEL_ERROR | Logger::LEVEL_WARNING,
                        'logVars' => []
                    ],

                ]
            ]);
        }
    ],
```

Comment: Seems like adding a
`'except' => ['yii\web\HttpException:404']`
to the target removes it from my streamlog

Answer (score 2):

Those should not be logged in `web.log` when running Craft 3.x, but rather in the `web404s.log` -- assuming you don't have `devMode` on (which it shouldn't be on for production...)

Vide: [Zen and the Art of Craft CMS Log File Reading](https://nystudio107.com/blog/zen-and-the-art-of-craft-cms-log-file-reading)

Also should you really want to customize things, it's not hard to do with Craft CMS, check out: [Creating a Custom Logger for Craft CMS](https://nystudio107.com/blog/creating-a-custom-logger-for-craft-cms)

Comment: I don't have devMode on, but I have changed to a the streamlog, but don't understand why that would enable it? I just can't have a file since I'm running in AWS ECS as a container. But I assume I could add an `except` config somehow to remove the `yii\web\HttpException:404` namespace?

Comment: I added a section on **Monolog as a Logger** that I think answers what you're trying to do here: [Creating a Custom Logger for Craft CMS](https://nystudio107.com/blog/creating-a-custom-logger-for-craft-cms#monolog-as-a-logger) (see the `'except'` key/value)

Comment: Nice, Monolog seems like a more versatile setup than yii2-streamlog.